# Chromadb + Langchain with SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction throwing sqlite3 >= 3.35.0 error, despite sqlite3 3.43.0 being available

Tags: sqlite, information-retrieval, langchain, chromadb

I have been trying to use

- `Chromadb` version `0.4.8`
- `Langchain` version `0.0.276`

with `SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction` as shown in the snippet below.

```
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from chromadb.utils import embedding_functions

# other imports
embedding = embedding_functions.SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
```

However, it throws the following error.

```
RuntimeError: Your system has an unsupported version of sqlite3. Chroma requires sqlite3 >= 3.35.0.
```

Funfact is I do have the required `sqlite3` (`3.43.0`) available which I can validate using the command `sqlite3 --version`.

Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: refer this https://docs.trychroma.com/troubleshooting#sqlite

Comment: I have the same problem. I get the error about the unsuported version of sqlite3 even if I have a version which should be supported (like the OP) and also when I _do not have sqlite3 installed at all_. @ZKS' link (which is also in the complete error message) gives several ways to get a supported sqlite3 version, but I am not sure this is actually the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message results from importing chromadb in Python:

```
>>> import chromadb
[...]
RuntimeError: Your system has an unsupported version of sqlite3. Chroma requires sqlite3 >= 3.35.0.
Please visit https://docs.trychroma.com/troubleshooting#sqlite to learn how to upgrade.
```

A workaround is suggested through the above url and the informative [source code](https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma/blob/747f7c6457fdea29394cdedcfd7cd0bc0541b3eb/chromadb/__init__.py#L57C4-L57C31) of Chroma. First

```
$ pip install pysqlite3-binary
```

Then, in Python:

```
>>> import pysqlite3
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules["sqlite3"] = sys.modules.pop("pysqlite3")
>>> import chromadb
>>>
```

which should now not produce any errors.

Fun fact:

```
$ sqlite3 --version
3.31.1 2020-01-27 19:55:54 3bfa9cc97da10598521b342961df8f5f68c7388fa117345eeb516eaa837balt1
```

while at the same time, continuing at the above Python console:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.43.1'
```

Comment: Is there a particular version of python required. I tried python 3.8.6 and 3.8.10 and neither can see pysqlite3-binary

Comment: @elbillaf, I'm using Python 3.8.10 right now, but if I remember well, it worked for several versions. Are you getting an error when pip installing pysqlite3-binary? What error?